# What does (void)char_ptr;?

Tags: c++, void

While reading a codebase I came across the following statement:

```
(void)data;
```

`data` is a `char*` type.

What does the above statement achieve?

Comment: It's a usual idiom to suppress warnings about unused parameters in functions. Effectively that statement does nothing.

Comment: There was no way to say a parameter or return value was unused before C++ 17 without using compiler/vendor-specific directives, so (void) was used to silence compiler warnings in a cross-compiler way. C++17 introduced [maybe_unused](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/attributes/maybe_unused) for this